# jQuery mouseout effect is not working.!

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a slider, when mouse hovers over logo the details will show, and when mouse hovers out from its parent div it should hide.

```js
jQuery('.st_inner img').mouseover(function() {
  jQuery(this).parent().siblings('#spon_detail').fadeIn();
});
jQuery('.sponsor_thumb').mouseout(function() {
  jQuery('#spon_detail').fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="key_val">
  <div class="st_inner">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x50">
  </div>
  <div id="spon_detail">
    <div id="dt_inner">
      <h4>Company Profile</h4>
      <?php 
              echo $spon_key;
            ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no element with the class `sponsor_thumb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the class on `img` element. There is no element using `sponsor_thumb` class

```js
jQuery('.st_inner img').mouseover(function(){
  jQuery( this ).parent().siblings('#spon_detail').fadeIn();
});
jQuery('.key_val').mouseleave(function(){
  jQuery('#spon_detail').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.key_val{
  width : 400px;
  height : 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="key_val">
    <div class="st_inner">
        <img class="sponsor_thumb" src="<?php echo $post_thumb ?>">
    </div>
    <div id="spon_detail" style="display:none">
        <div id="dt_inner">
            <h4>Company Profile</h4>                       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually .sponsor_thumb is outer div

Comment: So add it in your question too

Comment: i want when someone takes mouse away from .key_val div then #spon_detail should be hide...

Comment: look when you just moved away from image it hide...but i want when i come out from the whole then it should be hide...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166038/discussion-between-stack-overflow-and-owais-aslam).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achive but what you might be missing is hiding the element before you want to fade it in

```js
jQuery('.st_inner img').mouseover(function(){
  jQuery( this ).parent().siblings('#spon_detail').fadeIn();
});
jQuery('.sponsor_thumb').mouseout(function(){
  jQuery('#spon_detail').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#spon_detail{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="key_val">
    <div class="st_inner">
        <img src="<?php echo $post_thumb ?>">
    </div>
    <div id="spon_detail">
        <div id="dt_inner">
            <h4>Company Profile</h4>
            <?php 
              echo $spon_key;
            ?>                                  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am trying when cursor comes out  from the .key_val then #spon_detail should be hide

Comment: Then remember of using the right selectors. Try having the .key_val instead of .sponsor_thumb as a mouseout selector.

Comment: yes try but its not working, .sponsor_thumb  is parent class, so i was trying it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add `.st_inner img` on `mouseout` function.

```js
jQuery('.st_inner img').mouseenter(function() {
  jQuery(this).parent().siblings('#spon_detail').fadeIn();
});
jQuery('.key_val').mouseleave(function() {
  jQuery('#spon_detail').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#spon_detail{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="key_val">
  <div class="st_inner">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff">
  </div>
  <div id="spon_detail">
    <div id="dt_inner">
      <h4>Company Profile</h4>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also check this https://jsfiddle.net/a6ekejz5/1/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i should hide when cursor moves away from .key_val div

Comment: Then you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` function. Check the updated answer and fiddle.